# WCF Rest JSON Service Authentication with no Certificate

Tags: c#, android, ios, wcf, webhttp

I'm developing WCF Rest JSON service for Android and IOS Mobile apps. I need to provide some security to this..I gone through many Articles but most of them using Certificates.. Could anyone suggest which is the best and built in way to secure the service..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the use of OAuth (Since you are on multiple mobile platforms).
It does not use user/password authentication, you instead include OAuth inside the HTTP header.

Here is documentation and sample implementations;

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2011/01/20/oauth-2-0-and-odata-protecting-an-odata-service-using-oauth-2-0.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817102/Consuming-OAUTH-Enabled-Restful-WCF-Service-using

Comment: how to pass parameters while consuming through javascript in http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817102/Consuming-OAUTH-Enabled-Restful-WCF-Service-using I pass the parameters in consumeRest.js but its not working like                         var message =
        {
            action: accessor.serviceProvider.accessTokenURL,
            method: "GET",
            parameters: [{ "userid": "613", "pageno": "1", "pagesize": "1" }]
        };